# keep sub menu open and close on mouse down or page scroll

Tags: jquery, menu

The sub menu is hidden when mouse leaves the main menu.

But if mouse is over sub menu,then also sub menu hides.

I want to add functionality so that sub menu is hidden only if

#### 1) mouse is moved down of main menu

#### 2) if page is scrolled down

here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#main-nav li a.main-link").hover(function(){
$("#main-nav li a.main-link").removeClass("active");                                                 
$(this).addClass("active");                                      
$("#sub-link-bar").animate({
    height: "40px"                     
});
$(".sub-links").hide();
$(this).siblings(".sub-links").fadeIn();

});  

 $("#main-nav").mouseleave(function(){    

   $("#main-nav li a.main-link").removeClass("active");                                                                                     
  $(".sub-links").fadeOut();
  $("#sub-link-bar").animate({
     height: "10px"                     
  });           
  });
});
```

HTML code

```
<div id="sub-link-bar"> </div>

  <div id="wrap">

    <div class="roundfg">
 <ul id="main-nav">
  <li><a class="main-link" href="#">Home</a>
    <ul class="sub-links">
        <li><a class="main-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
  <li><a class="main-link" href="#">Tutorials</a>
  <ul class="sub-links">
    <li><a href="#" >Design</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">HTML &amp; CSS</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" >Other</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">PHP</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ruby</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Site Builds</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tools &amp; Tips</a> </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-35"><a href="#">Wordpress</a> </li>
   </ul>
    </li>


   <li><a class="main-link" href="#">Videos</a>
    <ul class="sub-links">
    <li><a href="#">Screencasts</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
   <li><a class="main-link" href="#">About</a>
    <ul class="sub-links">

    </ul>
   </li>         
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {

text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
    #wrap {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
background: url(body.png) center no-repeat;
min-height: 10px;
  }
    #body-image {
margin-top: 60px;
    }

   #main-nav {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
text-align: center;
min-height: 25px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }

 #main-handle {
width: 605px;
float: right;
margin-top: -1px;
   }

  #main-nav li {
display: inline;
list-style: none;
   }

  #main-nav li a {
margin-right: 5px;
font-size: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #f2f2f2;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 10px;
outline: 0;
position: relative;
top: -2px;
   }

   #main-nav li a:hover, #main-nav li a.active {
background: #587;
 }

   #sub-link-bar {
background: #907;
min-height: 10px;
border-bottom: #645546 1px solid;
 }

 .sub-links {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: -30px;
text-align: left;
left: 0px;
     }

   #main-nav li .sub-links li a:hover{
background: #2d2620;
 }

  #main-nav li a.close{
display: none;  
position: absolute;
 }

  #main-nav li a.close:hover{
background: #900;
 }

 .round {
 display:block
 }

 .round * {
display:block;
height:1px;
overflow:hidden;
font-size:.01em;
background:#645546
    }

 .round1 {
 margin-left:3px;
 margin-right:3px;
padding-left:1px;
padding-right:1px;
border-left:1px solid #443a30;
 border-right:1px solid #443a30;
background:#56493c
  }

 .round2 {
margin-left:1px;
margin-right:1px;
padding-right:1px;
padding-left:1px;
border-left:1px solid #322a23;
border-right:1px solid #322a23;
background:#594c3e
  }

 .round3 {
margin-left:1px;
margin-right:1px;
border-left:1px solid #594c3e;
border-right:1px solid #594c3e;
 }

   .round4 {
border-left:1px solid #443a30;
border-right:1px solid #443a30
    }

 .round5 {
border-left:1px solid #56493c;
border-right:1px solid #56493c
 }

 .roundfg {
background:#645546
 }
```

Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: $("#main-nav li a.main-link").removeClass("active");                                                 
$(this).addClass("active"); its unneccessary to remove class and add class?

Answer (score 0):

You dont require the `mouseLeave` event to be defined outside because `.hover(mouseEnter,mouseLeave)` provides in its list itself.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/ and http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#main-nav li a.main-link").hover(function(){ 
           $(this).addClass("active");                                      
           $("#sub-link-bar").animate({
                  height: "40px"
           });
           $(".sub-links").hide();
           $(this).siblings(".sub-links").fadeIn();
         },function(){
               $("#main-nav li a.main-link").removeClass("active");                                                                                     
               $(".sub-links").fadeOut();
               $("#sub-link-bar").animate({
                      height: "10px"                     
          });  
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this code snippet,the sub menu appears on main menu hover,but on sub menu hover the sub menu is not remaining open.The sub menu should be closed only when page is scrolled down or mouse is moved down.

Comment: in that case you have to provide your css properties too